# Problems obtaining a tag with a parent identical to the child using Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

This is my simple and troublesome code:

```
<html>
   ...
   <p>
      <font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
         <font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
            Hello
         </font>
      </font>
   </p>
   <div>
      ...
   </div>
   <p>
      <font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
         <font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
            Hello
         </font>
      </font>
   </p>
   ...
</html>
```

And I need to get these 2 tags and then delete their entire `<p></p>` parents

```
<font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
   Hello
</font>

<font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
   Hello
</font>
```

My wrong solution is

```
for x in soup.find_all('font', string='Hello'):
   x.find_parent("p").decompose()
```

But with these incomplete conditions, the iteration occurs 2 times for each tag because of the 2 identical parents:

```
<font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
      <font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
```

then the second time it doesn't find the parent because it was already deleted and an error occurs

Comment: There are many potential solutions. For example, you could make a list of the elements to delete, and only do so after you're done iterating over the results of the `soup.find_all()`.

Answer (score 1):

One of possible solution is to search for `NavigableString` instead for a tag. For example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = '''
<html>
   <p>
      <font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
         <font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
            Hello
         </font>
      </font>
   </p>
   <div>
    Something else.
   </div>
   <p>
      <font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
         <font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
            Hello
         </font>
      </font>
   </p>
</html>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

for font in soup.find_all(text=lambda t: t.parent.name=='font' and t.strip()=='Hello'):
    font.find_parent('p').decompose()

print(soup.prettify())
```

Prints:

```
<html>
 <div>
  Something else.
 </div>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm starting with python and scraping, this worked perfect for me. Thanks for your help